# How can I save my listview with Saved Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want develop Pomodoro app. I have edittext, countdowntimer, listview on my project. My app can work.And I have a lot of text on my list. my 3. countdown timer on finish I add text my listview. How can I save listview with sharedpreferences? and How Can I do this . Thanks A lot of

**main_activty.class**

```
public class pomodoro extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button baslat,backhome,bitir;
        EditText edittextcalisma,edittextmola;
        CountDownTimer calisma,mola;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
        ListView listView;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pomodoro);
            
          
            listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,R.layout.list_view,R.id.textitem, list);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            bitir=findViewById(R.id.bitirbutton);
            baslat = findViewById(R.id.baslatbutton);
            edittextcalisma = findViewById(R.id.edittextcalisma);
            edittextmola = findViewById(R.id.edittextmola);
           
            baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    closeKeyboard();
    
                    final int molapo = Integer.valueOf(edittextmola.getText().toString());
                    final int calismapo = Integer.valueOf(edittextcalisma.getText().toString());
    
                    if (calismapo <= 600 && molapo <= 600 && calismapo > 0 && molapo>0){
    
                        calisma = new CountDownTimer(calismapo * 60000, 1000) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millis) {
    
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                             
    
    
                                final int molapo = Integer.valueOf(edittextmola.getText().toString());
                  mola = new CountDownTimer(molapo * 60000, 1000) {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onTick(long millis) {
    
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinish() {
    
                                        pomodoro.setText("Bitti");
                                       
                                        CountDownTimer bekle = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onTick(long millis) {
    
    
                                            }
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFinish() {
                                                
                                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                                SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm");
                                                String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
    
    
    
                                                list.add("Çalışma Süresi : " + calismapo +"  dk  "+"\n"+  "Mola Süresi : " + molapo+"  dk  " +"\n" + datetime);
                                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
    
                                            }
                                        }.start();
                                    }
                                }.start();
                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put metadata in LUNCHER activity in order to work

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
```